# How to resolve com.couchbase.client.core.RequestCancelledException: Could not dispatch request, cancelling instead of retrying?

Tags: couchbase

I am using Cocuhbase client 2.5.0 jar as mentioned below.
1)couchbase-core-io-1.5.0
2)couchbase-java-client-2.5.0
3)rxjava-1.3.0

I follow the few blogs and suggestion of retry mechanism to change as  like this:
CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder().queryEndpoints(2)
                    .retryStrategy(BestEffortRetryStrategy.INSTANCE).build(); 
This is not working.
So any other suggestion welcome.

Comment: There's not enough here to answer why it's not working.  You shouldn't need to change the retry strategy.  My guess is you may have Couchbase 5.0 that has an authentication change and need to update your users/code for auth.  Maybe post how you're initializing the client?

Comment: we  are using Cocuhbase 4.6.0., cocuhbase SDK 2.5.0, Java 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 2.5.x, rather than using queryEndpoints, you should use the pooling configuration.  This will let the SDK dynamically create and shut down more connections as needed in case some of your queries take longer.  By saying `.queryEndpoints(2)`, you're saying only allow two connections, which may not be enough.

For something like this, try to diagnose it with:

```
CouchbaseEnvironment env = (CouchbaseEnvironment) DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
        .builder()
        .queryServiceConfig(QueryServiceConfig.create(2,50))
        .build();
```

That will give you a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 50 queryEndpoints.  You may have to adjust the max to your production workload, but if this makes the issue go away we know that you had exhausted the endpoints.